# Value pairs intersections in R

Tags: r, set, set-intersection

I have the following `matrix` in R, but with 22k entries.:

```
> unbalanced
      row  col
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    4    5
[3,]    4    6
[4,]    5    6
[5,]    9   10
[6,]    ...
```

Is there a way to divide this matrix into `sets` of intersecting data? 
What I mean is:
If there is an intersection between any rows, I want a set with the resulting union of those rows.
Ideally in the end I would have a list of non intersecting sets, that contain all the data from my original `matrix`.

Something like this (based on the above example):

```
[1,] 1  3
[2,] 4  5  6
[3,] 9  10
```

I have implemented something similar in python in the past (using iterations), but R is quite a different "beast", and the way perceive it iterations like `for` loops can and should be avoided.

Thank you in advance for any pointers you may provide.

Update:

Using @A. Webb's answer, using `aggregate(col~row,unbalanced,FUN=list)` gets me close to what I want, but there is still a missing detail that might not have been evident from the original question.
The mentioned solution, provides a list of sets which contain common data (which is what I called overlapping sets in the comments section).
To illustrate, further down in the list I get this:

```
        row   col
...
[160,]  160   c(161, 162, 194, 559, 1195)
[161,]  161   c(162, 194, 559, 1195)
...
```

What I needed was the union of these two sets, since their intersection is different from ∅ (empty set).
I should also add that I do not require the column named "row", so any solution that discards it is OK for me. I only need a list with the sets.

Comment: The clarified problem sounds like you are trying to identify what are called connected components in graph theory. You have a sparse matrix representation of an adjacency matrix (see `sparseMatrix` from `Matrix`), from which you wish to identify connected components (see `clusters` from 'igraph`, which is compatible with `Matrix`)